# constructing mechanical chase

Tags: hvac, vent, conduit

I'm thinking about putting a mechanical chase in my home to connect the roof to the garage.  The chase would contain the flue for water heater and furnace, and possibly a dryer vent (separate from flue).  I'd also like a conduit for communication cables (satellite, internet, etc).  I don't know if there are codes I need to be aware of, and this type of thing is hard to search for on Yelp.

[EDIT] I'm defining "chase" as a type of chimney or shaft.  Honestly, I don't know that I'm using the word correctly.  My water heater and furnace are in the garage, which sits underneath the main living area.  Both appliances are gas and they share a flue which goes from the garage (think basement), up through the main living area (in a closet surrounded by drywall - no access), and out the top of the flat roof.  I would like to move this about 3' so that I can make the corridor/chimney/shaft/chase bigger, and add a dryer vent and some conduit for cables.

Would any general contractor be able to do this, or should I look for specific labor?
Is this something I could DIY?

Comment: Can you please clarify what a "chase" is? A bit of research seems to indicate it's an access corridor for mechanical/electrical, but "to connect the roof to the garage"?

Comment: If you don't know if you're using it correctly, why are you using it? It only made this more confusing... Without seeing drawings or floor plans, this sounds ill-advised. As a wise person here once called me out for, it sounds like you're asking us to guide you through a specific solution without telling us the actual problem. What is wrong and what are you trying to accomplish? *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Is the garrage attached? Below? Or separate from the house? Normally a flu would go up not sideways.

Comment: @EdBeal see edit above.  Garage is below the house.  furnace flue goes up from garage, through the house, out the top of the roof

Comment: @HariGanti I want to vent my gas dryer up from the garage-below-living-area, out the top of the roof.  Just like the furnace flue is currently.  I would like to house both of these flues in the same "chimney" (please tell me the correct language to use).   I would also like a conduit so that I can send satellite tv cable from the roof, down into the garage.

Comment: Dryers aren't typically vented this way, in my experience. They are often placed along exterior walls to vent directly through the wall. Also, I don't know the acceptability of sharing chimneys/vents. You can get very strange backdraft phenomena if you aren't careful so I think everything requires a separate vent or some form of backflow arrestor to prevent carbon monoxide buildup. Again, you really need to post some drawings because there's a lot to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.   The dryer vent would be separate from the furnace flue.   I don't know if I can have both in the same chimney space, along with conduit for cables.  My main question is who would know this?  A specialist or a general contractor

Comment: HVAC contractors often install dryer vents since this is also ductwork. Depending on the scope many times a handyman contractor would be best. Get one to come have a look and give an estimate. You may find they recommend a different solution. Then decide if you can DIY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now we know the want is for the chase to be a verticle space with 2 or more vents and some electrical. Yes this can be done, enclosed vents are required to be triple walled pipe in my state and the wiring must be rated for the temp in that area. Many wire types are rated for 90deg C this is very hot and with some venting in the chase it will stay well below this threshold. The dryer vent may need a booster fan and can be single wall, I always suggest a booster when going verticle or more than ~15' horizontal.